# Apply filter to query for combobox based on field in current form

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

In a simplyfied version of my database, lets say I have 3 tables: Company, WorkUnit, Personel

- Company fields: cID (PK), cName
- WorkUnit fields: wID (PK), wcID (FK), wName
- Personel fields: pID (PK), pcID (FK), pwID (FK), pName

So how this works is you have a few companies in first table. In a second table you have a few working units, that belong to a company (there are multiple work units for the same company, and sometimes there is just one or none). In third table, you have personel that belong to either just the company or to the company and workunit (of course, this work unit needs to be one, that belongs to the company you choose for that person).

All foreign keys are actually in text, not in numbers (so for example, company with cID 3 is named Fruit Factory, so in Personel pcID field you don't write 3, but you write "Fruit Factory").

Also I have a query named qryWorkUnits (fields are wID, wName, wcID) for my "live filtering", which works with this code:

```
'Module
Public Sub FilterComboAsYouType(combo As ComboBox, defaultSQL As String, lookupField As String)
Dim strSQL As String
    If Len(combo.Text) > 0 Then
        strSQL = defaultSQL & " WHERE " & lookupField & " LIKE '*" & combo.Text & "*'"
    Else
        strSQL = defaultSQL    'This is the default row source of combo box
    End If
    combo.RowSource = strSQL
    combo.Dropdown
End Sub
'form for Personel table
Private Sub pwID_Change()
FilterComboAsYouType Me.pwID, "SELECT * FROM qryWorkUnits", "wName"
End Sub
```

Now what that does, is filter my combobox as I write in it so it narrows down my choices. But that means it offers me all the WorkUnits that match my writing, regardless of the Company this WorkUnit belongs to. I tried to insert all sorts of different parts in that code, but I can't get it to filter the query based on cID I have chosen in my Personel form. It sure must be possible to do that somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution. I needed to edit a bit of code and now it works as it should.
This is the final code:

```
Public Sub FilterComboAsYouType(combo As ComboBox, defaultSQL As String, lookupField As String, idField As String)
Dim strSQL As String
Dim curID As String
curID = Me.pcID
    If Len(combo.Text) > 0 Then
        strSQL = defaultSQL & " WHERE " & lookupField & " LIKE '*" & combo.Text & "*' AND " & idField & "=" & curID
    Else
        strSQL = defaultSQL    'This is the default row source of combo box
    End If
    combo.RowSource = strSQL
    combo.Dropdown
End Sub


Private Sub pwID_Change()
FilterComboAsYouType Me.pwID, "SELECT * FROM qryWorkUnits", "wName", "wcID"
End Sub
```